Magento 2 : Display All Cart Price Discount in Minicart
How to display all cart price rules discounts in minicart for M2.4.6 for those which can be calculated...
For example if the buyer buys more than 100 USD or similar. I am aware, that discount based on delivery address or payment cannot be displayed as customer in that point still did not choose proper delivery or payment options...
